# featherlight.js thumbnails into gallery

Tags: featherlight.js

I am going round in circles to create a thumbnail based media viewer (my example just uses images but videos can be in place on the original). The thumbnails to main image work just fine but I then wanted to add a "click main image to see large version".  This works. However, ideally I would like then have the previous/next buttons to cycle through the large size images from the thumbnail.  I do not wish to trigger the featherlight overlay when clicking on a thumbnail.

Here is my jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/2oux4tcw/4/

For reference here is my JS, html and CSS

**HTML**

```
        <div class="largeone" id="bigpic">
        <p class="info">Click a thumbnail</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbscon">
        <ul>
            <li><img id="img1" class="thumb galleryitem" data-featherlight-gallery src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/238943/fff.png&text=Green+Thumbnail"  data-largeone="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/238943/fff.png&text=Green+Largeg" alt="Green" title="Green Image"></li>
            <li><img id="img2" class="thumb galleryitem" data-featherlight-gallery src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/992323/fff.png&text=Red+Thumbnail"  data-largeone="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/992323/ffffff.png&text=Red" alt="Red" title="Red Image"></li>
            <li><img id="img3" class="thumb galleryitem" data-featherlight-gallery src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/232399/fff.png&text=Blue+Thumbnail" data-largeone="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/232399/ffffff.png&text=Blue" alt="Blue" title="Blue Image"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.largeone{background: #dedede; border: 1px solid #555; margin-bottom: 12px; height: 600px; width: 600px;}
.thumbscon ul{text-align: center; width: 600px;}
.thumbscon li{display: inline-block; margin-right: 6px; }
p.info{margin: 40% 35%;  display: inline-block; width: 30%; text-align: center;}
```

**JS**

```
var showLargeImage = function(elementId){       
    var el = jQuery("#"+elementId);
    var newMedia = "";
    if(el){     
        var imgsrc      = el.attr("data-largeone"); //large image source
        var imgtitle    = el.attr("title");
        var imgalt      = el.attr("alt");
        newMedia = jQuery("<img>",{src: imgsrc,title:imgtitle,alt:imgalt,id:"bigimage",class:"galleryitem"})
        newMedia.attr("data-featherlight",imgsrc);
        newMedia.attr("data-featherlight-gallery",imgsrc);
    }

    if(newMedia.length >0){
        jQuery("#bigpic").html(newMedia);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery(document).on("click","img.thumb",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            showLargeImage(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
        });

        jQuery(".galleryitem").featherlightGallery();

    });
```

Any pointers on how to trigger the gallery action from the main image only, but show the data-largeone images from the thumbnails?

Comment: Sorry about the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header   issues there...silly as the images have already been shown in the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you want exactly, but couldn't you simply create a hidden featherlight gallery, and redirect the click on the main image to the proper hidden thumbnail?

Comment: hmm interesting, perhaps I could redirect the click event to the original thumbnail